# Adding multiple prefix in a single route group in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, routes

Is there a way to add multiple prefix in a single route group in Laravel?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'prefix'], function (){
   Route::get('hello', 'HelloController@sayHello');
});
```

I have tried adding using pipe-

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'prefix1|prefix2'], function (){
   Route::get('hello', 'HelloController@sayHello');
});
```

Also tried using array-

```
Route::group(['prefix' => ['prefix1', 'prefix2']], function (){
   Route::get('hello', 'HelloController@sayHello');
});
```

But no luck. Is there really any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with `where` method call like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{prefix}'], function (){
    Route::get('hello', 'HelloController@sayHello')->where('prefix', 'prefix1|prefix2');
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to do it in more efficient way you can give a try for example:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{prefix}'], function (){
    $routes = [];
    $routes[] = Route::get('hello', 'HelloController@sayHello');
    $routes[] = Route::get('other', 'HelloController@other');
    foreach($routes as $route) {
        $route->where('prefix', 'prefix1|prefix2');
    }
});
```

But this is only the first idea that I have. Maybe you can find another better one.

Comment: It seems working. But if i need to group up 10-20 routes in this route group then it would be inefficient to add where clause to all of them. So, is it not possible to do it in more easier way?

Comment: Probably you'll need to add some helper function or something to make it more clean. I'll suggest you one in my entry.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Just for your info - If you use this approach then remember that all your controller's action under this route will receive prefix variable as a first argument because it will be treated as route params.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add one more example, just for handle occasional cases:

```
// The Route Name point to multiple prefixes 
// according to locale using the same Controller

$contactRoutes = function () {
    Route::get('', ['uses' => 'ContactController@index', 'as' => 'contact');
    Route::post('', ['uses' => 'ContactController@send', 'as' => 'contact.send');
};
switch (env('APP_LOCALE')) {
    case 'pt': 
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'contato'], $contactRoutes);
        break;
    case 'es':
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'contacto'], $contactRoutes);
        break;
    default: //en
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'contact'], $contactRoutes);
        break;
}
```